# unsubscribe to a newsletter

Tags: php, email, newsletter, unsubscribe

I want to add a linf to unsign to my newsletter. I can't succeed to give my variable  "email" in the newsletter.
I send the newsletter to some email in the same time
$template allow to the newsletter to get data from database,and my newsletter in in html with variables like this: {{variable}}
I tried to put my code template in my while, but the email is still the first emai.
Do you have an idea?

here's the code:

```
if($_POST['recipients']) {

    $template = file_get_contents('template/emails/newsletter.html');

    $addresses = explode(';', $_POST['recipients']);
    $subject = stripslashes($_POST['subject']);
    foreach($addresses as $address) {

    $newsletter_unsign =  ' <a href="http://dev.cater2.me/unsign-newsletter.php?id='.$address.'">Unsubscribe from the newsletter</a>.';

    $template = str_replace(array('{{newsletter_top_bar}}','{{newsletter_top}}','{{newsletter_title1}}','{{newsletter_body1}}','{{newsletter_title2}}','{{newsletter_body2}}','{{newsletter_title3}}','{{newsletter_body3}}','{{newsletter_side_title}}','{{newsletter_side}}','{{newsletter_bottom}}','{{newsletter_footer}}','{{newsletter_unsign}}'),
                  array($_POST['newsletter_top_bar'],$_POST['newsletter_top'],$_POST['newsletter_title1'],$_POST['newsletter_body1'],$_POST['newsletter_title2'],$_POST['newsletter_body2'],$_POST['newsletter_title3'],$_POST['newsletter_body3'],$_POST['newsletter_side_title'],$_POST['newsletter_side'],$_POST['newsletter_bottom'],$_POST['newsletter_footer'], $newsletter_unsign),
                  $template);


        $address = trim($address);

        sendMail($address, $subject, str_replace('{{c2me_tracking_link}}', 'http://cater2.me/?ref='.urlencode(c2me_encrypt($address)), $template), true);
    }

    notif('E-mail(s) sent');
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_POST['recipients']) {

    $original_template = file_get_contents('template/emails/newsletter.html');

    $addresses = explode(';', $_POST['recipients']);
    $subject = stripslashes($_POST['subject']);

    foreach($addresses as $address) {

      // You should have made sure before/outside the foreach loop, that the e-mails are well-formatted and valid
      $address = trim($address);

      $this_template = $original_template;

      $newsletter_unsign =  ' <a href="http://dev.cater2.me/unsign-newsletter.php?id='.$address.'">Unsubscribe from the newsletter</a>.';

      $this_template = str_replace(array('{{newsletter_top_bar}}','{{newsletter_top}}','{{newsletter_title1}}','{{newsletter_body1}}','{{newsletter_title2}}','{{newsletter_body2}}','{{newsletter_title3}}','{{newsletter_body3}}','{{newsletter_side_title}}','{{newsletter_side}}','{{newsletter_bottom}}','{{newsletter_footer}}','{{newsletter_unsign}}'),
                  array($_POST['newsletter_top_bar'],$_POST['newsletter_top'],$_POST['newsletter_title1'],$_POST['newsletter_body1'],$_POST['newsletter_title2'],$_POST['newsletter_body2'],$_POST['newsletter_title3'],$_POST['newsletter_body3'],$_POST['newsletter_side_title'],$_POST['newsletter_side'],$_POST['newsletter_bottom'],$_POST['newsletter_footer'], $newsletter_unsign),
                  $this_template);

      sendMail($address, $subject, str_replace('{{c2me_tracking_link}}', 'http://cater2.me/?ref='.urlencode(c2me_encrypt($address)), $this_template), true);
    }
    notif('E-mail(s) sent');
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You only fetch `$template` from the file once, but then you try to replace it multiple times. After the first replace, it is fixed with the first recipient's data.

Try assigning the replaced string to a new variable, e.g. `$template_after_replace`:

```
if($_POST['recipients']) {

  $template = file_get_contents('template/emails/newsletter.html');

  $addresses = explode(';', $_POST['recipients']);
  $subject = stripslashes($_POST['subject']);
  foreach($addresses as $address) {

    $newsletter_unsign =  ' <a href="http://dev.cater2.me/unsign-newsletter.php?id='.$address.'">Unsubscribe from the newsletter</a>.';

    $template_after_replace = str_replace(array('{{newsletter_top_bar}}','{{newsletter_top}}','{{newsletter_title1}}','{{newsletter_body1}}','{{newsletter_title2}}','{{newsletter_body2}}','{{newsletter_title3}}','{{newsletter_body3}}','{{newsletter_side_title}}','{{newsletter_side}}','{{newsletter_bottom}}','{{newsletter_footer}}','{{newsletter_unsign}}'),
              array($_POST['newsletter_top_bar'],$_POST['newsletter_top'],$_POST['newsletter_title1'],$_POST['newsletter_body1'],$_POST['newsletter_title2'],$_POST['newsletter_body2'],$_POST['newsletter_title3'],$_POST['newsletter_body3'],$_POST['newsletter_side_title'],$_POST['newsletter_side'],$_POST['newsletter_bottom'],$_POST['newsletter_footer'], $newsletter_unsign),
              $template);


    $address = trim($address);

    sendMail($address, $subject, str_replace('{{c2me_tracking_link}}', 'http://cater2.me/?ref='.urlencode(c2me_encrypt($address)), $template_after_replace), true);
  }

  notif('E-mail(s) sent');
}
```

As an improvement, you can just run the replacement once (before the `foreach` loop to replace things that won't change (e.g `$_POST['newsletter_top']`), then individually replace `$newsletter_unsign` within the `foreach` loop, but I will leave that as an exercise for the OP.